# Is there a way to know the last ./configure options when compiling apache from source?

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration

If it's PHP,it can be checked by `phpinfo();`,

is there anyhow to know the `./configure ...` detail of how apache is built?

Comment: Previously answered: http://serverfault.com/questions/122562/how-to-fetch-configure-parameters-used-at-last-time/122593#122593

Answer (score 2):

if you still have the directory it was compiled in, you can look at the `config.log` though i'm not sure if apache uses that 'standard', there may be another log file, of sorts, you can try finding it by using `grep './configure ' *`

i don't know if it will provide you with all you want to know, but it provides you with a /ton/ of information about how your server is configured:

```
<IfModule mod_info.c>
    # Allow remote server configuration reports, with the URL of
    #  http://servername/server-info (requires that mod_info.c be loaded).
    # Change the ".example.com" to match your domain to enable.
    #
    <Location /server-info>
        SetHandler server-info
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.1
    </Location>
</IfModule>
```

you will want to change 127.0.0.1 to your IP address, unless you are doing this from the localhost.

in your apache httpd's configuration file, and then adding `mod_info` to your loaded modules will allow you to browse to `http://example.com/server-info` in your browser and see all sorts of configuration details.

Comment: Agreed - that's about as close to a "correct" answer as I can think of in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

Many configure scripts, including the one that comes with apache, have an option for help, try

```
./configure --help
```

or

```
./configure -h
```

To see the list of build options.

Comment: That's not what the OP is asking about.