# How do I find out original ./configure compile time directives for Apache?

Tags: apache-2.2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to fetch ./configure parameters used at last time?](https://serverfault.com/questions/122562/how-to-fetch-configure-parameters-used-at-last-time)

I've inherited an abandoned server, and I need to upgrade Apache/OpenSSL.

No one knows the original configure options that were used to compile it, and the original admin is long gone.

PHP is not compiled in, so phpinfo()'s out.

http -l and httpd -V do some good, but not enough to rebuild all of the ./configure line.

I need to get all of the arguments that were used to build it including the "enable" parameters,etc..

Where does phpinfo() get this from?  Is there another way to find it?

Thanks!

Comment: This isn't a duplicate asI don't have a config.status to refer to. Given ONLY the executable, CAN YOU FIND OUT THE COMPILE TIME DIRECTIVES?

Answer (score 3):

man apache2 said
      -V     Print the version and build  parameters  of  apache2,  and  then
              exit.
The informations are not exactly the configure options, but the Makefile options. So I think you can retrieve your configure options like that.

For apache 1, I don't know

Comment: Some, but not really.  Like, when it was built where did configure expect to find openSSL?  It's not in httpd -V.  httpd -V is also referenced in the original question.

Thanks though.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Apache apache puts a config.status file in the same directory from which ./configure was originally run.  This file seem to be usable for running the ./configure again using the same parameters.

I hope this helps someone else!

Thanks!

Comment: What if the system in question DIDN'T have the source directories from which it was built still lying around (you wouldn't have config.status)?