# Save options passed to a './configure' script?

Tags: configuration

Is there any "conventional" way to save options passed to a `./configure` script?

On the rare occasion that I need to build something from source, I generally need to pass it non-standard configure options (eg, `--prefix=...`, `--with-foo=...`, etc)… Then when I eventually need to re-build it, I've forgotten all the options I originally used.

Currently I use something like this:

```
$ mv configure{,.real}
$ echo "./configure.real --prefix=... --with-foo=..." > ./configure
$ chmod +x ./configure
```

But that feels… Less then ideal.

Comment: Duplicate: http://serverfault.com/questions/122562/how-to-fetch-configure-parameters-used-at-last-time/122593#122593

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As well as `config.log`, most `configure` scripts will create a `config.status` script which will be executable, and when you run it will do the `configure` with the same options you did originally.

You should be able to just do `./config.status`

Answer (score 1):

After `./configure` you normally have a `config.log` file containing the `./configure` command (including option) as well as the software name. I use to keep this one.